# when i replace jersey annotations with spring rest it throw exception 404 Not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-jersey

I got 404 exception, when i replace jersey annotations with spring rest annotations.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the url, you are trying to access?

Comment: Was this class part of @ApplicationPath?

Comment: Spring-Applicatin has a good logs. Look in the log. Do you see lines about mapping "/student/display" path? Any errors or warnings? What starting port do you see in the log? What URL do you trying to use?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/student/display

Comment: i am using spring boot version 1.2.7

Comment: Pls add your pom.xml

Comment: Did you setup `server.servlet.context-path`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class annotated with @Componentscan in your root package , if you don't it's normal to hava a 404 not found in this case. With jersey in order to expose a rest api you need to register it.